# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named qrcode - after used pyinstaller to get exe files

Tags: pyinstaller

I have develop a python file to generate a QRCode used the **qrcode**  from https://pypi.org/project/qrcode/ in the PyCharm.

it is the example of code:

```
import qrcode
qr = qrcode.QRCode(
            version=4,
            error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_M,
            box_size=40,
            border=0)
data = "My text on QrCode"
qr.add_data(data)
```

It works well in the PyCharm, but when I created a EXE file, I got error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named **qrcode**

After that, I have added the name of module **(qrcode)** in the *--hidden-import* parameter, but it not solve the issue.

I have used a virtual environment into PyCharm and I found a **qrcode** folder as below:
[image]

Could you someone give me some idea how to solve it?

thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using pip to install qrcode into the system python and not just in the virtual environment?

Comment: HI @Davidsherriff, yes, I did it in the python folder. but the exe file do not works!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, my solution was to upgrade auto-py-to-exe

run:

```
pip install --upgrade auto-py-to-exe
```

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I add new interpreter with selection chekbox "inherit global site-packages"
and on it create new configuration.
its work for me.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gC0lw.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaUPc.png)